# Why does (In Recovery) indication show up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, recovery

I just noticed that this database is currently in "In Recovery" mode.

How do I change back to normal mode (without (In Recovery))?

This is very active database, and I am trying to be very careful with what is going on.

[image]

**Update**: The "In Recovery" indication disappeared.
Why is it doing it?
Only thing that I did was Stop and Start SQL Server.

Comment: What does the error log say for this database on startup (the previous one, not the one you just did)? And what happens if you run `DBCC CHECKDB`

Comment: @Charlieface  I am not sure what you meant on the 1st part of your comment. But, when I ran DBCC CHECKDB, this is result : CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'PCCReport'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16 The log is turned over on each restart so make sure you get the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start SQL Server, what is called "recovery" is performed for each database. This basically consist of three steps:

1. Analysis
2. Redo (make sure that operations done for the data but wasn't yet written do disk at shutdown is there, using the transaction log)
3. Undo (rollback the stuff that wasn't committed at startup)

The same type of recovery is performed when you failover if you use Always On Availability Groups, btw.

Redo should not take more than 1 minutes for hard shutdowns since this is the default setting in SQL Server (there are both server and database setting for this).  For proper shutdowns redo time will be very quick.

Undo takes as long as it has to take.

There is a setting introduced in 2019 called Accelerated Database Recovery which will cause recovery to be very quick, but there is a cost involved when you modify data. However if recovery is a frequent issue for you, then this option should at least be considered.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the [target recovery time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/change-the-target-recovery-time-of-a-database-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) of the database or [CHECKPOINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/checkpoint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the database before shutdown.